# Going from development to production and dealing with URLs with DeployHQ

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, deployment

I recently launched a wordpress website using deployHQ

However, I still have to work on the project and deploy it every few days or so

The problems are the URLs, htaccess and wp-config files. Everytime I deploy, I have to change all the URLs, and upload a different htaccess and wp-config file

Is there a way to make all this smoother ?

Answer (score 0):

With [DeployHQ](https://www.deployhq.com), you can create config files which are uploaded as part of the deployment process. You can also exclude specific files from being uploaded, even if you haven't placed them in your `.gitignore` file. Hope that helps!